# io.write() isn't writing to the console when a sleep function is called afterwards

Tags: lua

I'm attempting to create a simple iterative output system in Lua. The code is pretty easy to understand.

```lua
function IterativeReader.read(Text)
    local Length = string.len(Text)
    
    for Pos = 1,Length do
        io.write(string.sub(Text,Pos,Pos))
        Sleep(ReaderSpeed)
    end

    for i = 1,NewlineCount do
        io.write("\n")
    end
end
```

You see, I need to use `io.write()` as the `print()` function automatically creates a newline, which is not desired behavior. However, the issue arises when the `Sleep` function (see below) is added. Using a busy wait function causes the same issue.

```lua
function Sleep(t)
  os.execute("sleep "..tonumber(t))
end
```

The entire string is output after the full time has passed. This issue is specific to `io.write()`, as `print()` works just fine with it.

Comment: Start your program with `io.stdout:setvbuf('no')` to disable output buffering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just do `io.write(...)`, your output is buffered. Do `io.flush()` right before sleeping to force the output to be actually written then.

Comment: Solved the issue.

Comment: @marfit If this solved your issue, please accept it with the check mark.